# Same day, same customer but different branch transactions

Tags: sql-server, count, partition, case-when

I have a table that contains Account Number, Transaction Date, Transaction Branch and amount.

I would like to generate a column that contains the information of:

> if that specific customer, made a transaction from different branches on the same day.

An example of result is shown below:

```
    AccountNumber   Transaction_branch  tran_Date   Amount  Different_Branch_Tran
    11452           331                 20/07/2020  500     no
    11452           331                 21/07/2020  500     no
    5432            14                  22/07/2020  500     no
    5432            14                  22/07/2020  500     no
    11452           14                  24/07/2020  500     yes
    11452           420                 24/07/2020  500     yes
    11452           14                  26/07/2020  500     no
```

I have a code that shows me if a customer made a same amount of transaction on the same day. however I couldn't figure it out how to modify or change this code to get the result I want.

```
 select 
    a.*,
    case when count(*) over(partition by trandate, accountnumber, amount) > 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end SameAmountSameDay
from Tran_table  a 
where trandate> '20190701'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.....
case when 
min(Transaction_branch) over(partition by AccountNumber, tran_Date, Amount) 
= 
max(Transaction_branch) over(partition by AccountNumber, tran_Date, Amount) 
then 'No' else 'Yes' 
end as SameAmountSameDayDifferentBranch
.........
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use an `EXISTS` and a subquery, as you can't use `DISTINCT` in a windowed `COUNT`:

```sql
SELECT TT.AccountNumber,
       TT.Tranasction_branch,
       TT.tran_date,
       TT.Amount,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1
                        FROM dbo.Tran_table sq
                        WHERE sq.AccountNumber = TT.AccountNumber
                          AND sq.Tran_Date = TT.Tran_Date
                          AND sq.Tranasction_branch != TT.Transaction_branch) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Different_Branch_Tran
FROM dbo.Tran_table TT
WHERE TT.trandate > '20190701'; --This is called Tran_Date in your sample data, are these different columns?
```

Comment: even though it seems working, due to i work with very large data, query takes too much time (1h 43m and still going)

Comment: That query shouldn't take that much time, unless you're severly lacking indexes, @Cemil .